# Upper bound on the variance of norm of random vector

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Recently I came across a paper that made an unproven assumption; it goes as follows, for $X \in \mathbb{R}^n$,  $$ \mathbb{E}[X]= \bar x, \quad \mathbb{E}[\|X-\bar x\|^2] \leq \beta \|\bar x\|^2 + \sigma^2$$
where $\beta$ and $\sigma^2$ are non-negative contants. Is there a way to see the posible middle steps?

Comment: Citing the paper in question would be helpful here...

Comment: https://arxiv.org/abs/1810.08313, pp. 14, assumption 3.